# Collapsing navbar looks distorted - Bootstrap, Less how to make navbar collapse on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using Bootstrap and Less to make a website.

However, trying to make navbar collapse on smaller screens for mobile friendly website and it shows up collapsed even at full screen width (aware I can change the size of screen at which it collapses) and looks wrong.

The navbar was working and looked fine before I added the code to make it collapse.

Here is my html for my navbar

```
  <div class="header clearfix">
    <nav class="text-center">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">


  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button></ul>


<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav nav-navpills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>



      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Services <span class="caret"></span></a>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Search engine Optimisation</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social media management</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Online marketing</a></li>
</ul>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="About us.html">About us</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Any help much appreciated. I am a complete beginner so please go easy on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be sorted out with an @mediaquery and setting the size of the screen at which you want the navbar to collapse.